# Get two raw bytes from a single char

Tags: java

Size of `char` in Java is two bytes. How can I get raw `byte`s from a `char` variable?

```
var ch = '文';
var b1 = // ?
var b2 = // ?
```

Comment: note that a single `char` does NOT cover all Unicode code points...

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  I doubt you want to convert only a single char to bytes;  if you are converting a String to bytes, there are much better ways to do it than converting one character at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform bitwise arithmetic on `char` to access the individual bytes:

```
var b1 = (byte) ch;
var b2 = (byte) (ch >> 8);
```

```
System.out.printf("%02x %02x\n", b1, b2);
// 87 65
```

Comment: Why mask `ch & 255`? Why not just `(byte)ch`?

Comment: @user229044 Good point, no good reason, especially since I didn’t do it for the second byte. I’ll change it to make it consistent. (I think my rationale was to make explicit to the reader that we are aware that the cast truncates the value of `ch` but the context should make this clear anyway.)

Comment: What is the more significant byte here - b1 or b2?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Cool, I'm not a Java developer, so I really wasn't sure if I was missing something about how casting works.

Comment: @RA Since you only shift for `b2`, `b2` must be the most significant byte.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably just simple math.

```
  byte b1 = (byte)(0xFF & ch);
  byte b2 = (byte)(0xFF & (ch >> 8));
```

Let us know if this works for you.  Be aware that `byte` is signed and this will yield negative numbers about half the time.